# Error :The deployment parameters are using case sensitive names. The error parameter name(s): name.(ARM template deployment)

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template, routetable

I am creating ARM template for Route table creation. A simple ARM template downloaded from the template deployment is failing. After I run the ARM template, it asks for the name and throws the below error.

[image]

I have tried giving names like routeVnet, vnetroute etc.
Saw some posts where giving the combination of lowercase uppercase in name will fix the issue. But it doesn't work here.

The arm template:

```
 {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.5",
        "parameters": {
            "name": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "location": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "tagsByResource": {
                "type": "object",
                "defaultValue": {},
                "metadata": {
                    "description": "Optional tags provided by the user via createUiDefinition.json"
                }
            },
            "disableBgpRoutePropagation": {
                "type": "bool"
            }
        },
        "variables": {},
        "resources": [
            {
                "apiVersion": "2019-02-01",
                "type": "Microsoft.Network/routeTables",
                "name": "[parameters('name')]",
                "location": "[parameters('location')]",
                "tags": "[ if(contains(parameters('tagsByResource'), 'Microsoft.Network/routeTables'), parameters('tagsByResource')['Microsoft.Network/routeTables'], json('{}')) ]",
                "properties": {
                    "disableBgpRoutePropagation": "[parameters('disableBgpRoutePropagation')]"
                }
            }
        ],
        "outputs": {}
    }
```

*The parameter template*:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "location": {
            "value": "eastus"
        },
        "Name": {
            "value": ""
        },
        "tagsByResource": {
            "value": {}
        },
        "disableBgpRoutePropagation": {
            "value": true
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please add the ARM template here?

Comment: I have updated the code in the question. Thanks

Comment: This works fine for me, created a route table with name "routeVnet" using this template. What name are you providing?

Comment: The same I have provided the same now  .Issue is still there.

Comment: az deployment group create --resource-group test --template-file ./route.json --parameters ./routeParameters.json
Please provide string value for 'name' (? for help): routeVnet
{"error":{"code":"CaseSensitiveDeploymentParameterNamesFound","message":"The deployment parameters are using case sensitive names. The error parameter name(s): name. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-keyvault for usage details."}}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with your parameter file where you are passing parameter **name as "Name"**, in template your parameter is **name** while in parameter file you have mentioned it as **Name**.

The correct parameter file will look like:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "location": {
            "value": "eastus"
        },
        "name": {
            "value": "routeVnet12"
        },
        "tagsByResource": {
            "value": {}
        },
        "disableBgpRoutePropagation": {
            "value": true
        }
    }
}
```